# Unity Движение объекта в противоположную сторону от точки касания на экран

Tags: unity3d, motion

Как в Unity сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на экран, все объекты которые находятся рядом разбегались в разные стороны?

Comment: Какой вопрос, такой ответ: 1. Определяете место, куда указывает нажатие. 2. Находите объекты, которые в нужном радиусе от точки нажатия. 3. Перемещаете найденные объекты/вызываете их метод передвижения.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я так понимаю, вопрос в том, как сделать само движение. Только-что протестировал, всё работает как надо. Сделать проверку, рядом ли с мышью находятся объекты можешь через Physics2D.OverlapCircle. Если тебе какие-то моменты в коде не понятны - не стесняйся задавать вопросы, постараюсь ответить.

```
using UnityEngine;
public class Cube : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Vector2 _direction;
    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Mouse0))
        {
            Vector2 diff = transform.position - Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
            _direction = diff.normalized;
        }
        transform.Translate(_direction * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Я делал точно также, только у меня движение объектов было через **rb.velocity** ,